# JQuery problem IE8 name attribute

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

In IE8 this

```
input.attr("name","exam.exam_Normal['" +normal_id_unique + "'].boolean_v");
```

Outputs this only in IE8....

```
<input propdescname="exam.exam_Normal['1'].boolean_v" type="hidden" value="0"/>
```

WHY WHY?? Why everywhere are problems... why

Comment: Save the ranting and describe your problem properly; what exactly is not working? It seems to output exactly what you want. Doesn't it work in other browsers or what? Or does it output `propdescname` when you try to put `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name attribute you are assigning <strike>is invalid</strike> looks strange.

I think what you *may* really want to do is to use the actual variable value:

```
input.attr("name",exam.exam_Normal[normal_id_unique].boolean_v);
```

Provided that variable really exists in your script.

Comment: well i removed the ' ' and worked as i want:) thank you for the advice

Comment: The HTML `name` attribute's content model is CDATA, not a `NAME` token (which is used for IDs). It is valid to include `[]` in `name`, and almost every PHP application does.

Answer (score 4):

This error only shows up in the IE8 developer tools (F12) - in the DOM the name attribute will still be correctly set. See this [post for more](http://weblogs.asp.net/jacqueseloff/archive/2009/04/17/creating-dynamic-forms-with-mvc-and-jquery.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, just like said bobince that attribute name displays only in the IE8 developer tool.
The real DOM attribute will be exactely the attribute you assigned.

Answer (score 0):

> Outputs this only in IE8....

How do you cause that to be ‘output’? Normally you only see `propDescName` (and `submitName`) when debugging the DOM in the developer tools. It is an internal detail of IE8-running-in-IE7-mode's implementation of the `name` attribute, that should not normally be visible to scripts.

(Setting the `name` attribute has notorious problems in IE up to version 7, so it's generally best avoided unless you really know what you're doing. In particular, though it correctly sets the ‘control name’ used to submit the field value, it won't affect radio-input grouping, frame targeting, or update the `form`[`.elements`] lookup.)